# How do I tell Angular to install a subset of Clarity's modules?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

How do I install a set of Clarity's submodules?

My app is taking a little too long to bootstrap. It looks like one of the reasons is that I am importing ClarityModule in AppModule, and ClarityModule has many submodules and dependencies. I only need to use about a dozen of Clarity's components, so I would like to try importing only a small set of Clarity's submodules. Just importing the submodules doesn't work. So if I put this into AppModule:

```
import { ClrMainContainerModule } from '@clr/angular/layout/main-container';
...
@NgModule({
imports: [ClrMainContainerModule,
...
```

The Typescript linter seems to be fine with that, but when I `ng serve`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/Modules/AppModule.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@clr/angular/layout/main-container' in 'c:\Users\jzabinski\repos\hachart-client\projects\hachart-view\src\app\Modules'
```

Subsequent research shows that the error is coming from Webpack. I don't know whether my goal is possible, and if possible, whether I can make changes on the Typescript/Angular side to make the CLI happy, or whether I need to reconfigure Webpack.

I made a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfuczh). The error appearing in the Stackblitz version actually involves the use of the submodule's component in AppComponent, and is different from the error that I'm getting back from the CLI, but the root cause seems to be the same: my ignorance of how to import a submodule.

Expected: I need a way to only install a small subset of Clarity's full functionality
Actual: I don't know of a way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE September 17, 2019:
  Jeremy Wilken answered this question in some comments on other answers: "...we do ship each component as a submodule but Angular CLI tree shaking will drop the unused modules. We publicly export all of our submodules, so... Use `import { ClrAccordionModule } from '@clr/angular';` if you really want to import just one component module." My mistake lied in trying to import from the submodule's folder (@clr/angular/layout/main-container) instead of the intended folder (@clr/angular).
  But if you're using Ahead of Time compilation, this whole question becomes somewhat moot. See the original answer below.

Original Answer

Outside of the other helpful answers on this post, I found what I consider to be the true root cause; it was embarrassingly mundane. The ClarityModule was being compiled because we were unintentionally using Just In Time compilation. Our production build was using Ahead of Time compilation due to our use of the `--prod` flag, but I am serving my development build for testing purposes using plain old `ng serve`. That uses Just In Time by default, as noted in [the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler).

I assumed that the two builds were the same, but that was wrong, and was why we were getting a pause of more than a second when navigating to the app. Once I used `ng serve --aot` instead of `ng serve`, there was a long pause in the CLI while factory objects were compiled for all of the templates, and then the app started running more quickly.

In other words, I couldn't really entertain the possibility of using a leaner Clarity build because it just isn't available right now, but moreover, my lack of performant software was happening due to another cause.

Comment: Since you are using the Angular CLI, there is no 'leaner' Clarity build because we've already done the work to separate the modules by components. Unused modules get dropped, but some modules are dependencies of other modules so they might be retained (such as icons are used in multiple places). With Ivy, there is potential for a way to tree shake down to the individual component level, but until then this is the most lean we can make it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Angular CLI, you can rest assured that Angular will tree shake out any submodules in Clarity that you aren't using. So you shouldn't be manually importing individual submodules or you're likely to miss something like is the case here.

The only time you would like to import submodules is for testing cases, because usually testing is not configured to do build optimization, so it would in fact bootstrap the whole `ClarityModule` for each test when that isn't necessary.

Comment: Okay, so to extend the example a wee tad, how would one import a submodule for a testing case? Would it just be a question of using the `import` keyword as usual?

Comment: Sorry, but are you sure that’s how tree shaking works in angular? I am fairly sure that sub modules that are imported can not be automatically tree-shaked, regardless of actual usage. (at least pre-ivy) That’s why the pattern of single component modules became popular.

Comment: We have separated our components into their own modules, and unless you use one of the components declared inside of one of those modules they get tree-shaken out. I've tested it as long as you use the production builds.

Comment: To include just one submodule, you just do `import { ClrDatagridModule } from '@clr/angular';` as we ship all modules in our public API.

Answer (score -2):

That probably won't work and is not how it should work. You basically want to go around the "public API" of the library and consume some internals directly.

Even if you get webpack on board with this, this is risky and prone to break. For example, there might be providers in the main module that are necessary.

You have two options here:

- Convince the library maintainers to export the submodule independently.
- Fork/copy the repo and add only the module code you need.

Comment: Upvoted this as the answer because this answers the question asked in this post. See the answer to my own question elsewhere in this post for considerations as to why you are thinking of importing Clarity's (or any third-party library's) submodules.

Comment: This is incorrect, we do ship each component as a submodule but Angular CLI tree shaking will drop the unused modules. We publicly export all of our submodules, so you don't need to follow this advice and it is very unwise to fork and modify the source code if you want to ever update. Use `import { ClrAccordionModule } from '@clr/angular';` if you really want to import just one component module.